# Time Machine cannot find external toshiba hard drive after OS X 10.9.2 update

Tags: macos, time-machine, hard-drive, backup, external-disk

I used my Toshiba Canvio USB 3.0 external hard drive without any problems for the past year.  Today, I received a system alert:

> Backup failed. The backup disk "Time Machine Backups" is not available

[Other Mavericks OS users with similar issues. from apple.com forums](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3510032?start=90&tstart=0)

My `Console` output is below:

```
4/24/14 10:26:52.131 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.hidden.daemon[579]) Job appears to have crashed: Trace/BPT trap: 5
4/24/14 10:26:52.131 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.hidden.daemon) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
4/24/14 10:26:52.189 PM ReportCrash[559]: Saved crash report for Hidden[579] version ??? to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Hidden_2014-04-24-222652_MYMBPr.crash
4/24/14 10:26:53.515 PM com.apple.backupd[530]: Starting manual backup
4/24/14 10:26:53.515 PM com.apple.backupd[530]: Error -35 while resolving alias to backup target
4/24/14 10:26:53.518 PM com.apple.backupd[530]: Backup failed with error 18: The backup disk could not be found.
4/24/14 10:26:53.704 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[193]: (com.hp.help.tocgenerator) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
4/24/14 10:26:54.553 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[193]: (com.hp.help.tocgenerator) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
4/24/14 10:27:02.352 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.hidden.daemon[588]) Job appears to have crashed: Trace/BPT trap: 5
4/24/14 10:27:02.352 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.hidden.daemon) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
4/24/14 10:27:02.408 PM ReportCrash[559]: Saved crash report for Hidden[588] version ??? to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Hidden_2014-04-24-222702_MYMBPr.crash
4/24/14 10:27:04.790 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[193]: (com.hp.help.tocgenerator) Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds
4/24/14 10:27:06.125 PM com.apple.launchd.peruser.503[193]: (com.hp.help.tocgenerator) Throttling respawn: Will start in 9 seconds
4/24/14 10:27:12.565 PM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.hidden.daemon[591]) Job appears to have crashed: Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

My `Disk Utility` shows the Toshiba External USB 3.0 Media hard drive as plugged in but it is greyed out. It shows `S.M.A.R.T. Status: Not Supported`, `Partition Map Scheme: GUID Partition Table` and `Write Status: Read/Write`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my `Toshiba Canvio 1TB USB 3.0 hard drive (3 year warranty)` is busted as I plugged it in my PC to check and it was not recognized there either.  I suspect I leave it plugged in too long; It's plugged in to my USB hub.

It's still under warranty so I mailed it to [Toshiba Support](http://support.toshiba.com/warranty) for store credit.

Answer (score 1):

Go to /Macintosh HD > Library > Preferences, move to the trash the file com.apple.TimeMachine.plist and restart the Mac.

Open Time Machine Preferences and "Choose" or "Add" the disk as a Backup Disk. The following backup will be added to the existing ones.

Comment: Thanks. I followed your instructions. When I go to `Time Machine Pref > Select Backup Disk`, my hard drive doesn't display.  Only option I have is `Other Time Capsule: Set up a Time Capsule that is not listed here`